# Program for copying image files works incorrectly

Tags: python, image, python-2.7

So basically I have this piece of code to copy an image file `abc.jpg` to `abc2.jpg`:

```
path = raw_input('Enter the file path: ')

with open(path, 'r') as file:
    path = path.split('.')
    path[0] = path[0] + '2'
    path = '.'.join(path)
    with open(path, 'a') as out:
        for each in file:
            out.write(each)
```

I don't know a lot about image files, so I used this to see if it works as for text files. The result is that the new file `abc2.jpg` **is** created, but is not openable. The image viewer simply says `The file may be unsupported, damaged or corrupted.` (I know that system commands could be used but this is for another program that has to send files byte-wise)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: open those files in binary mode: `rb` and `ab`.

Comment: Thanks! That was fast and simple. Wow.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `with open(path, 'rb') as file:` for reading as bytes

And then `with open(path, 'wb') as out:` for overwriting the file as bytes, not as append `'a'`

If you keep running the script with `'a'` it'll just keep tacking data on to the end of the file... probably not what you want.